# How to read 'Version' attribute of XSD schema element <xs:schema

Tags: c++, xml, qt, xsd, schema

I'm trying to implement XSD schema versioning and I'd like to use the optional XSD schema attribute named 'version', but I'm unsure how to read it using Qt XML patterns library.

Example :

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
      targetNamespace="http://www.example.org/ns/personName/1" 
      xmlns:namens="http://www.example.org/ns/personName/1"
      version="1.5"> 
...
```

I'd like to be able to extract the XSD version, then compare this with an actual element with protocol version element in XML doc.

Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: I believe Qt XML patterns has support for XPath and you should be able to parse the XSD as a regular XML file and retieive the values.

Comment: Thanks - I've come to the same conclusion that I will simply parse as normal XML and extact what I need that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parse XSD as an XML document then extract the parts needed.